# How to filter a lot of data with IPC::Open2?

Tags: perl, ipc, pipe, popen, binutils

My task is to filter some data from perl script with external utility  (the addr2line). The data size is quite large. I need to print a lot of data to `stdin` of program and read a lot of data back (from `stdout` of program into my script).

Now I do this with `IPC::Open2`, but I don't mix reading and writing. Is this legal? Will `Open2` buffer any size of data in pipe?

My code:

```
my $cmd="addr2line -e $prog_name ";
use IPC::Open2;
local (*Reader, *Writer);
my $pid = open2(\*Reader, \*Writer, $cmd);
for(@requests) {  # this array is HUGE, 100s of thousands of entries
    print Writer "$_\n";
}
close Writer;  
for(@requests) {
    $function_name = <Reader>;
    $filesource = <Reader>;
   #... store ..
}
close Reader;
waitpid($pid,0);
```

Comment: Good news. You can mix writing a line and reading of two lines because addr2line does "`fgets(stdin)`" and "`fprintf;fprintf;fflush(stdout);`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will run into buffer capacity constraints the way your program is written. Your input buffer (`Reader`) will fill up and block execution of your external program.

Mixing reading and writing would help, as you would be emptying the input buffer at about the same rate that the external program is filling it.

Another thing that would help is using files for interprocess communication instead of pipes or sockets (as `IPC::Open2` does). Then you would be limited only by the amount of free disk space. You could do it yourself, though [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper) uses files for IPC by default.

```
use Forks::Super 'open2';

...
my ($Reader,$Writer,$pid) = open2(@command);
for (@requests) { print $Writer "$_\n" }
close $Writer;
for (@requests) { ... read ... }
close $Reader;
waitpid $pid,0;
```

Comment: Is Fork::Super standard or it is CPAN? The program is addr2line from binutils

Comment: Mixing reading and writing helps, because addr2line is designed to works with pipes. It flushes its output for every input line. And it does fgets in loop to read the input.

Answer (score 3):

Pipes have limited sizes. Your approach will deadlock

```
  Parent                 Child
  ------                 -----
  ...                    ...
                         Wait for data in Writer
  Put data in Writer
                         Read data from Writer
                         Put data in Reader
                         Wait for data in Writer
  Put data in Writer
                         Read data from Writer
                         Put data in Reader
                           => Blocks cause Reader is full
  Put data in Writer
  Put data in Writer
  ...
  Put data in Writer
  Put data in Writer
    => Blocks cause Writer is full
```

One possible solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use threads;
use IPC::Open2 qw( open2 );

my @cmd = ("addr2line", "-e", $prog_name);

local (*Reader, *Writer);
my $pid = open2(\*Reader, \*Writer, @cmd);

my $thread = async {
   for (;;) {
       $function_name = <Reader>;
       last if !defined($function_name);
       $filesource = <Reader>;
       #... store ..
   }

   close Reader;
};

{
   my @requests = ...;

   for(@requests) {  # this array is HUGE, 100s of thousands of entries
      print Writer "$_\n";
   }

   close Writer;
}

$thread->join();
waitpid($pid, 0);
```

Alternatively, [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IPC%3a%3aRun) has tools that will make this easy too.

The unixy way would be to use [IO::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/IO%3a%3aSelect), but that's a real pain.

Comment: `$thread = async` - what minimal perl version is needed to do this?

Comment: @osgx, 5.6, I think? You need a threaded build of Perl, though.

Comment: Looks right. How can I test if my perl build is threaded or not?

Comment: @osgx, `perl -v` will tell you, e.g. `i686-linux-thread-multi`

Comment: When I try "`perl -e 'use threads; $thr = async {print "123";};'`" - it says: "`(The 'useithreads' configuration option hasn't been used.)`"

Comment: @osgx, You could use [`perlbrew`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?App::perlbrew) to locally install a newer version of Perl (`perlbrew install perl-5.14.1 --as=perl-5.14.1t -D=usethreads`). You could also use IPC::Run instead of threads.

Comment: I tried the above solution, but stumbled on the following problem. Due to Perl's thread process state copying, the close() isn't propagated to the process, and thus the reading end never sees an EOF. I ended up using  IPC::Run, which seems to be using select() internally, and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @Diomidis Spinellis , Yes, I would definitely recommend using IPC::Run without direct use of pipes